# How to write foreach loop in controller along with blade code?

Tags: laravel

I am going to do ajax search. i have passed all the value from ajax to the controller and find data with the help of that values.
now i want to display it back to the view. for that i need to write blade code in laravel.
i have tried

```
$output ="";
foreach($cv as $key=>$cvs){
  $output.='<tr>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidatename.'</td>'. 
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateemail.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidategender.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidatedob.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidatecontactnumber.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateoptionalcontactnumber.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateQualification->academicqualification.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateQualificationType->academicqualificationtype.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.foreach($cvs->languageProficiency as $lp){$lp->languages->language - $lp->candidatelanguageproficiency}.'</td>'.
}
```

i tried using foreach loop like this but it didn't work. shows me error (Unexpected Foreach).
So how can i write foreach loop in controller along with blade code.

Comment: Have you read the [blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating the table in php instead of javascript?

Comment: @Rwd I thought it would be easy to use foreach loop in controller rather than in js response.

Comment: Are you just passing the html back or are you passing other data as well? Please can you show all the code you have for the route/controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this code helps.

```
$output ="";
foreach($cv as $key=>$cvs)
{
  $output.='<tr>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidatename.'</td>'. 
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateemail.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidategender.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidatedob.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidatecontactnumber.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateoptionalcontactnumber.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateQualification->academicqualification.'</td>'.
 '<td>'.$cvs->candidateQualificationType->academicqualificationtype.'</td>';

$languageProficiency = '';
 foreach($cvs->languageProficiency as $lp)
 {
 $languageProficiency = $lp->languages->language - $lp->candidatelanguageproficiency;
 }

 $output. = '<td>'.$languageProficiency.'</td>'.
}
```